# looping different php array to display different elements

Tags: php

I am printing content to an html page and the came content is being printed i'm trying to display the 5 different entries.

```
<?php
       $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM $itemTable ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5";
       $selected = $db->query($sql2);
       ?>

                 <h3 class="like">Recommended</h3>
       <?php while($reccomendedItem = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selected)) :?>
         <p><?php echo $reccomendedItem['ProductName']; ?></p>
                 <ul id="example">

        <li><img src="images/pic11.jpg" class="img-responsive" /><div class="grid-flex"><a href="#"><?php echo $reccomendedItem['ProductName']; ?></a><p><?php echo $reccomendedItem['ProductPrice']; ?></p></div></li>
        <li><img src="images/pic10.jpg" class="img-responsive" /><div class="grid-flex"><a href="#"><?php echo $reccomendedItem['ProductName']; ?></a><p><?php echo $reccomendedItem['ProductPrice']; ?></p></div></li>
        <li><img src="images/pic9.jpg" class="img-responsive" /><div class="grid-flex"><a href="#"><?php echo $reccomendedItem['ProductName']; ?></a><p><?php echo $reccomendedItem['ProductPrice']; ?></p></div></li>
        <li><img src="images/pic8.jpg" class="img-responsive" /><div class="grid-flex"><a href="#"><?php echo $reccomendedItem['ProductName']; ?></a><p><?php echo $reccomendedItem['ProductPrice']; ?></p></div></li>
        <li><img src="images/pic7.jpg" class="img-responsive" /><div class="grid-flex"><a href="#"><?php echo $reccomendedItem['ProductName']; ?></a><p><?php echo $reccomendedItem['ProductPrice']; ?></p></div></li>

                 </ul>

         <?php endwhile; ?>
```

This produces the same information in productName for each 5 items.

Comment: the loop should be inside the `<ul>` wrapping `<li>`'s

Comment: In each instance of while, you print 5 items, so of course you will see 5 times the same value.  If you expect 5 values out of the database, move your while inside the `<ul>` and print only 1 `<li>` per loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

You should only have 1 `<li>` tag inside the loop. If you put all 5 in the loop, it will make 5 copies of the same thing every time it goes through the loop. Also you `<ul>` tag should start and finish outside of the loop, otherwise it will be re-inserted every pass.

Try:

```
<ul id="example">
  <?php while($reccomendedItem = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selected)) :?>
    <li><img src="images/pic11.jpg" class="img-responsive" /><div class="grid-flex"><a href="#"><?php echo $reccomendedItem['ProductName']; ?></a><p><?php echo $reccomendedItem['ProductPrice']; ?></p></div></li>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```